# Have a picnic vs make a picnic vs go on a picnic vs go for a picnic

Tags: collocations

I quite often come across the following phrases:

> - Have a picnic
> - Make a picnic
> - Go on a picnic
> - Go for a picnic

But I can't distinguish between them. Are they the same or do they have different meanings?

Answer (score 2):

I will take a stab at this. "Have a picnic" is the standard expression and in general usage  applies to someone whether they are just attending the picnic or actually planning and/or running the picnic. "Making a picnic" is non-idiomatic for either attending or planning, but perhaps would be acceptable for a caterer or cook who actually prepares the picnicking food and accoutrements. "Go on a picnic" is also considered non-standard, but I would venture to say is not terribly non-idiomatic.  In other words one hears it more and more. In actual usage I would say it is used indistinguishably from "have a picnic", though to my ears it sounds more appropriately reserved for attending as opposed to planing a picnic.  Interestingly enough "go for a picnic" sounds less problematic than "go on a picnic" at least in the case of "let's hop in the car and go for a picnic". I do think that this does place emphasis on either the distance away from one's present location, or a dramatic change in pace or activity.

I should also point out that you are leaving out the most basic form i.e.,just "picnic"as a verb.

Comment: Yes. To my BrE ear, you can quite naturally suggest ***having** a picnic* even if you're just going to throw a blanket down on the back lawn, but that wouldn't be far enough away to suggest ***going** for a picnic*. I could imagine a slight connection to *going **on/for** a walk* (where ***on*** tends to "elevate" the activity, perhaps to something more organised / extended), but I'm not sure that really applies to picnics.

Comment: In the US it is common to have people say that they could "go for a picnic" implying that they desire to have a picnic.